# Delete files to Trash on OS X

Tags: osx, deletion

Is there a best, most future-proof method of setting emacs on OS X to delete files to the trash?

I tried the instructions [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SystemTrash):

```
(setq delete-by-moving-to-trash t)

(defun system-move-file-to-trash (file)
  "Use \"trash\" to move FILE to the system trash.
When using Homebrew, install it using \"brew install trash\"."
  (call-process (executable-find "trash")
    nil 0 nil
        file))
```

but they don't work:

```
Trashing...
(wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
```

Also, it feels wrong to have to install a separate program in order for Emacs to be able to trash files. Furthermore, I won't remember to install the "trash" program the next time I do a clean OS X install.

Update: I added this to my .emacs and removed the call to `trash` and it seems to work. I wonder why Emacs on OSX defaults to the FreeDesktop `~/.local/share/Trash` location.

```
(setq trash-directory "~/.Trash")
```

Comment: You should file a bug report for this.

Comment: sent a bug report.

Comment: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21340

Comment: You might want to checkout the `osx-trash` package on MELPA https://github.com/lunaryorn/osx-trash.el

Comment: // , Even ELPA is screwing this up, apparently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187765/why-does-emacs-attempt-to-use-local-share-in-osx-even-when-not-run-as-ro

Comment: @waymondo Thank you! This should be an answer, not just an inconspicuous comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is required:

```
(setq delete-by-moving-to-trash t)
(setq trash-directory "~/.Trash")
```

The function `move-file-to-trash` has three tests:  **(1)** whether `trash-directory` is defined; **(2)** whether `(fboundp 'system-move-file-to-trash)`; and, **(3)** `(t . . .` the *catch-all* that uses `~/.local/share...`  The *second* test always fails on OSX 10.6.8 when built with the standard option of `--with-ns`.  I don't have access at the moment to other versions of OSX.

Comment: However OS X al tracks where the file came from if you use trade from the finder and that does not occur here - so note this is not a full implementation but often good enough

Answer (score 4):

Define the function `system-move-file-to-trash` in this way should be enough:

```lisp
(defun system-move-file-to-trash (file)
  (call-process "trash" nil nil nil file))
```

if you don't have `trash` installed, Emacs will tell you. then, don't set the variable `trash-directory` since `trash` does that for you.

About Emacs's trash behavior:

> move-file-to-trash is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘files.el’.
>
> (move-file-to-trash FILENAME)
>
> Move the file (or directory) named FILENAME to the trash. When
>   ‘delete-by-moving-to-trash’ is non-nil, this function is called by
>   ‘delete-file’ and ‘delete-directory’ instead of deleting files
>   outright.
>
> If the function ‘system-move-file-to-trash’ is defined, call it  with
>   FILENAME as an argument. Otherwise, if ‘trash-directory’ is non-nil,
>   move FILENAME to that  directory. Otherwise, trash FILENAME using the
>   freedesktop.org conventions,  like the GNOME, KDE and XFCE desktop
>   environments.  Emacs only  moves files to "home trash", ignoring
>   per-volume trashcans.

I guess `(setq trash-directory "~/.Trash")` is not working: Finder will not be able to recover these files since it (at least) doesn't know where these files come from.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the [osx-trash](https://github.com/lunaryorn/osx-trash.el) package.  It works with or without the `trash` command line utility, and integrates properly with the macOS Trash directory.

Comment: Without the `trash` command line utility you can ear the trash sound.  With the `trash` command line utility it's faster.

Comment: As of April 2021 the package now calls trash with a-F argument which users Finder to do the trashing, so you get the sound and also when you look at the file in trash with Finder you get the Put Back option

Answer (score 0):

According to my investigation (on MacOS 10.14 with Emacs 28.0.50).

#### For those, who DON'T really need `"Put Back"` feature

It's enough to configure:

```
(setq delete-by-moving-to-trash t)

(if (eq system-type 'darwin)
    (setq trash-directory "~/.Trash"))
```

`delete-by-moving-to-trash` is available/updated since `Emacs 23.1`.
`trash-directory` is available/updated since `Emacs 23.2`.
So this is expected to be a working solution for many (or majority) of `MacOS` `Emacs` users.

#### For those who DO want to use `"Put Back"` feature

The issue is not something specific to `Emacs` app only. On `MacOS`, `"Put Back"` feature is enabled only for those files that were deleted by `Finder`. (At least it [used to be so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707618/put-back-items-from-trash-programmatically) and works this way on my system too.)

Possible workarounds:

- Use the package [osx-trash](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/osx-trash) (with/out `brew install trash`).
- `brew install trash` and call `trash -F` command from an init-file. Examples to base the solution on: [osx-trash package code](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/osx-trash/tree/af74a2055a15bf4182d8196600f7decd66eec634) or [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SystemTrash).
- Do not install `trash` library, but call `Finder` with an `Applescript`. Examples to base the solution on: [osx-trash package code](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/osx-trash/tree/af74a2055a15bf4182d8196600f7decd66eec634) again or [use ns-do-applescript](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/osx-trash/issues/4).
- Use [Emacs Mac port](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/src/a124e5d0ccb820095be99c78d51abfd36ee22d9b/src/mac.c#lines-2155) that more fully integrates `Emacs` into `MacOS`. There's a [Homebrew](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport)  adaptation of this package.
- Implement in `Emacs` core. (That's a bit separate topic, so I'm just mentioning the possibility.)