# Deleting a file to ~/.Trash produces "File already exists..." if a file of that name is there

Tags: dired, osx, deletion

I have `(setq trash-directory "~/.Trash")` and `(setq delete-by-moving-to-trash t)` in `.emacs` to be able to have files moved to `~/.Trash` via `d` and then `x` in `dired-mode`. (This is in macOS.)

But if I want to delete a file (= move to the trash) that already exists in ~/.Trash, then I get error `file-already-exists: File already exists: /Users/<myuser>/.Trash/<myfile>`.

How can I specify in `.emacs` to (force-)overwrite files in ~/.Trash if they already exist in ~/.Trash?

Alternatively, how can I get Dired `d`-then-`x` to create a `~1`, `~2` etc. version in Trash, every time a new file of the same base-name is moved there?

Comment: It all should work as you request.  what exact version of emacs have you got? Also the only thing I have different is I don't set trash-directory and just leave it as nil

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have `GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.20 Version 10.14.3 (Build 18D109)) of 2019-09-02`. I also tried it without `(setq trash-directory "~/.Trash")`. I can then indeed delete a file, but I don't see it in ~/.Trash (so also not overwriting one that's already in ~/.Trash). I perhaps simply removes the file then or uses some other trash I'm not aware of.

Comment: The function that should be called is move-file-to-trash SO try running atht and see if it does what you want

Comment: Ah, this failed (instead of the current file at point or selected, it tries to delete the whole folder the current file resides in, which fails due to missing permissions). But I saw from the error message that the 'trash' it that's used is `~/.local/share/Trash/files` instead of `~/.Trash`. So just the wrong folder so to say (but then changing that with `trash-directory` creates the original problem

Comment: Then I think you have set something special - does this happen with `emacs -Q`

Comment: Ah, I need to select the file again when I do M-x move-file-to-trash, okay, that clarifies that. But then both with my .emacs and with emacs -Q, the behavior remains the same: The file is moved to the wrong trash (and deleting ~/.local/share/Trash just recreates it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete files to Trash on OS X](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15009/delete-files-to-trash-on-os-x). Had you mentioned that you're on OSX, the fact that this is a duplicate question might have been discovered sooner.

Comment: Thanks, Drew, yes (see my answer). I didn't update my post since macOS as OS was clear from my second comment above (or so I thought).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user `mmmmmm`, I found the solution. I saw [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15009/delete-files-to-trash-on-os-x) that it's a macOS problem. Installing `osx-trash` (via MELPA) and then using

```
(when (eq system-type 'darwin)
  (osx-trash-setup))
(setq delete-by-moving-to-trash t)
```

in `.emacs` solved the problem (it now moves files to ~/.Trash and creates temporary names in ~/.Trash in case there is already a file with the same name).